# how to conditionally not create beans in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, javabeans

In my application, I have a component that reads data from other system when the application is started.
However, during testing, I don't want this component to be created

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DeviceStatisticsSyncHandler {
    @EventListener
    public void handle(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        syncDeviceStatisticsDataSync();
    }

    @Value("${test.mode:false}")
    public  boolean serviceEnabled;
}
```

I can use condition to solve this, but other code readers need to understand, so I don't think this is a very good method:

```
@EventListener(condition =  "@deviceStatisticsSyncHandler .isServiceEnabled()")
public void handle(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    syncDeviceStatisticsDataSync();
}

public  boolean isServiceEnabled() {
    return !serviceEnabled;
}

@Value("${test.mode:false}")
public  boolean serviceEnabled;
```

My application doesn't use Profiles, is there any other method to solve this problem.

Spring Boot version:2.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is not to load the `DeviceStaticsticsSyncHandler` at all if you're in a test mode.
The "test.mode" is not a good name here, because the production code contains something tightly bound to the tests.

How about the following approach:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name ="device.stats.handler.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing=true) 
public class DeviceStatisticsSyncHandler {
   // do whatever you need here, but there is no need for "test.mode" enabled related code here
}
```

Now in Tests you can define a test property "device.stats.handler.enabled=false" on the test itself or even place that definition in `src/test/reources/application.properties`  so it will be `false` for all tests in the module.

An obvious advantage is that this definition is pretty much self explanatory and can be easy understood by other project maintainers.

Comment: Load beans into the application context if some condition is met is a good method，and I use this method load different DataSource in test and product environment,I decided to use this method. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

for me, it's not the case of the condition rather environment-related. I will solve this problem using spring profile.

**Step 1:** Create an Interface first

```
public interface DeviceStatisticsSyncHandler {

    public void handle(ApplicationReadyEvent event);
}
```

**Step 2:** Create an Implementation for production

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class DeviceStatisticsSyncHandlerImpl implements DeviceStatisticsSyncHandler {
            @EventListener
            @Override
            public void handle(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
                syncDeviceStatisticsDataSync();
            }
        }
```

**step 3:** create an implementation of test

```
@Component
 @Profile("test")
 public class DeviceStatisticsSyncHandlerTestImpl implements DeviceStatisticsSyncHandler {
                @EventListener
                @Override
                public void handle(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
                    //do Nothing
                }
}
```

**final step**

All you need to do is set/toggle the property

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

**or**

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve this without any further external configuration required.

The idea is to create a general configuration that applies to all integration tests and use `@MockBean` there to replace the real bean. So one should create a class like this under the `test` classpath (i.e. that is not scanned during normal application launch):

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration
{
   @MockBean
   public DeviceStatisticsSyncHandler deviceStatisticsSyncHandler;
}
```

I was actually surprised that `@MockBean` can be used here, but the Javadoc explicitly points that out: `Can be used as a class level annotation or on fields in either @Configuration classes, or test classes that are @RunWith the SpringRunner.`.